# Create a local flutter package for myself

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a local package for my multiple projects.

This is a package with lot of base-designs (think of it as a toolkit)

The problem is that I can't generate my package to add it easily in my projects.
I would like to generate it as a "pub" package but without publishing it on the internet and without putting it on a git

So, I opened Visual Studio Code, pressed CTRL+ALT+P, created a new flutter project and selected "packages" names "toolkit_flutter"

I created a "src" folder in "lib" and created a little class with a Text widget.
In "toolkit_flutter", I added "export 'src/blabla.dart';" to export my design.

And this is where i'm stuck...

I tried to add a path in "dependencies:" in my pubspect.yaml but I have errors:

> The directory 'C:/Users/Naografix/Desktop/toolkit_flutter' doesn't
> contain a pubspec. Try creating a pubspec in the referenced directory
> or using a path that has a pubspec.dart(path_pubspec_does_not_exist)

So I changed the path destination to itself and:

> Publishable packages can't have 'path' dependencies. Try adding a
> 'publish_to: none' entry to mark the package as not for publishing or
> remove the path dependency.dart(invalid_dependency)

Then, I added "publish_to: none" and got this error:

> [toolkit_flutter] flutter pub get Running "flutter pub get" in
> toolkit_flutter...                  Error on line 13, column 3 of
> pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.

What can I do?

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: toolkit_flutter
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
homepage:
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies: 

  toolkit_flutter:
    path: "C:/Toolkit Flutter/toolkit_flutter" 

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the "A package may not list itself as a dependency." error message, you gave your private dependency the same name as the package that depends on it (`toolkit_flutter`).  Give them different names.  Your private package itself should not need to list any special dependencies in its `pubspec.yaml`.

In other words:

### In your private package:

```yaml
name: toolkit_flutter
description: My private Flutter toolkit library.
version: 0.0.1
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies: 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

### In your application:

```yaml
name: my_cool_application
description: My cool Flutter application.
version: 0.0.1
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies: 
  toolkit_flutter:
    path: "/path/to/toolkit_flutter" 

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! I probably use a wrong command to generate my pub for my private package: "flutter pub publish --dry-run". Do you know if it's the right command? Because I imagine a flutter package like a DLL (in C#). I would like to create & generate a package that I can use it in my other app!

Comment: @Naografix You shouldn't be using `pub publish` for a package that you want to keep *private*.  The `pubspec.yaml` file should be created when you first create your Dart/Flutter project (e.g. `flutter create ...`).  You can just create it yourself if necessary.

Comment: But I don't understand: I currently have 3 Flutter App. I would like to create an external toolkit to "gather" my main design. So I created a flutter package with VSCode (original post) and now I don't understand how to generate a "dll like". I can"t reference my toolkit with a hard path in my apps because a friend of mine will help me on my 3 apps

Comment: @Naografix Your "DLL-like" package would just be a directory with a `pubspec.yaml` file and a `lib/` subdirectory.  That would correspond to the package named `toolkit_flutter` in my example.  As for a hard-path, I don't understand.  That's contrary to the premise of your question, which is that you want a private package that is referenced by a file-system path.  If you want to share it with someone, make a Git repository (possibly on your own Git server).

Comment: @Naografix If what you actually want to do is publish your Dart package to your own private server instead of to `pub.dev`, then see https://dart.dev/tools/pub/custom-package-repositories.